# What is the difference between running a java springboot project in an IDE and using maven clean package?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I am new to Java Springboot and I have been tinkering with it for a while now (implement caching ).

I am trying to recreate the **

> samples/coherence-spring-demo/coherence-spring-demo-boot project

** in the following Github repo https://github.com/coherence-community/coherence-spring following the instructions in https://spring.coherence.community/3.1.0/refdocs/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#coherence-spring-documentation

I have been working on VS Code with the STS extension and when I click on run, the application runs fine. But when I build it using

> mvnw clean package

I get the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project coherence-spring-demo-boot:
> Could not resolve dependencies for project
> com.oracle.coherence.spring:coherence-spring-demo-boot:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT:
> com.oracle.coherence.spring:coherence-spring-demo-core:jar:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT
> was not found in
> https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots during a
> previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and
> resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of
> snapshots-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
> the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full
> debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors
> and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR]
> [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

I have checked the pom.xml file and the dependency has been added and also checked the nexus repository to find the same package.

If it could resolve the dependency while running the application while running, why could it not have found the dependency while trying to build it?

Also can you tell me what the difference between Run as spring-boot app and building the package is in springboot? and

Comment: Btw, while running, VS Code tells me that the build has failed, however I still have the option to proceed which lets the app run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Run as Spring-boot app** -> Startup Embedded Tomcat server (or ThymeLeaf or Jetty) along with your spring boot application (Starts up IOC container, initializes beans , dependencies etc internally )

**mvn clean package** ->

1. mvn -> Maven command
2. clean -> Maven goal, which cleans (`removes`) classes, resources and artifacts available as part of `Target` folder
3. package -> Maven `phase`, which packages your application (`In JAR or WAR` whichever specified in POM) and puts the artifact in your local repository

**Maven is a build tool `i.e.` It provides a basic structure of how your project should look like or be organized. For example, which file stays where, place for your external resources, dependencies etc**

**While, Spring-boot is a module of Spring framework which can be simply run as Java application**

Read more on mvn here

[https://www.journaldev.com/33659/maven-build-lifecycle-phases-goals#:~:text=Maven%20goals%20represent%20a%20specific,goals%20through%20the%20command%20line.&text=Here%20is%20an%20example%20to,goal%20from%20the%20command%20line](https://www.journaldev.com/33659/maven-build-lifecycle-phases-goals#:%7E:text=Maven%20goals%20represent%20a%20specific,goals%20through%20the%20command%20line.&text=Here%20is%20an%20example%20to,goal%20from%20the%20command%20line).

Spring boot features and technicals here

https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot